A reference of an inequality
I am looking for a reference of the special functions where I can find this inequality:
$$\alpha \beta \leq e^{\alpha }+ \beta (\log{\beta }-1),\quad \text{for}\,\, 
\alpha, \beta > 0.$$
Thank you in advance

This follows simply from maximizing the function $\alpha \mapsto \alpha \beta - e^{\alpha}$ over $\mathbb{R}$, which is nothing more than a calculus problem. One can interpret this inequality as expressing the fact that the Legendre dual $f^$ of $f = \exp$ is given by $f^(\beta) = \beta (\ln(\beta) - 1)$ for $\beta > 0$, but I’m not sure there’s a reference for this basic fact.

Ok, thank you @.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate#Table_of_selected_convex_conjugates

Consider the function $f(x)=e^x$, then
$$f'(x)=f''(x)=e^x>0,\quad \forall x\in\mathbb R.$$
the tangent line of $f$ at $(x_0,e^{x_0})$ is
$$y=e^{x_0}(x-x_0)+e^{x_0}=e^{x_0}x+e^{x_0}(1-x_0).$$
Take $x_0=\log\beta$, then $e^{x_0}=\beta$, the tangent line of $f$ at $(\log\beta,\beta)$ is
$$y=\beta x+\beta(1-\log\beta).$$
As $e^x$ is convex function, so
$$e^x\geq\beta x+\beta(1-\log\beta).$$
Let $x=\alpha$, we get
$$\alpha \beta \leq e^{\alpha }+ \beta (\log{\beta }-1).$$
For example,the tangent line at $(0,1)$:


It should be $x= \alpha$ :)

@
Davide Masi
Yes, thank you! Fixed it now!

Consider the function
$$f(\alpha,\beta)= e^{\alpha }+ \beta (\log(\beta)-1)-\alpha \beta  $$ Compute the partial derivatives
$$\frac{\partial f(\alpha,\beta)}{\partial \alpha}=e^{\alpha}-\beta\qquad \text{and}\qquad \frac{\partial f(\alpha,\beta)}{\partial \beta}=-\alpha+\log(\beta)$$ Set them equal to $0$ to obtain $\beta=e^\alpha$.
$$f(\alpha,e^\alpha)=0$$
If you use directional derivatives and multivariable Taylor series around $(0,1)$
$$f(\alpha,\beta)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\alpha -(\beta-1)\right)^2 \, t^2 +\frac{1}{6} \left(\alpha ^3-(\beta-1)^3\right)\,t^3 +O(t^4)$$ where $t\to 1$.
Have a look at the accepted answer here.
